# install older version of php in xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, downgrade

I am using xampp for my development, however the bundled version is 1.5.3, our servers are only 1.5.2.6 hence, I need to downgrade php so I dont use any 5.3 features.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get older versions of XAMPP from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/) that contain the appropriate PHP version for your needs.